# Virtualmin user increasing quota

Tags: hosting, webmin, virtualmin

I'd like to know if it’s possible for a user under a host using Virtualmin to increase / decrease his domain quota. If so, how?

I have tried several things but none seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do within Virtualmin, as well.

For the domain owner user, you would click "Edit Virtual Server" and in the section labeled "Quotas and limits" you can change the quotas to whatever you like, and then save it.

For regular email/FTP users, click "Edit Users", click the username of the user you want to edit and then change the quota in the section labeled "Quota and home directory settings", and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, instead of going through Virtualmin, simple increase your space via Linux command.
Virtualmin wont even be aware